# java invokation of button

Tags: java, swing, events, invoke, vaadin6

I have a page with constuctor.

So, I have a button, and when this button is clicked, then function handleLogin starts to work.

Comment: Have you tried to call it? Just handleLogin(); after this.passwordField.setValue(pass);

Comment: What line of handleLogin() throws NullPointerException? This should be because it tries to get something that's not loaded.

Comment: debug it and see what is making it fail. Meaby with a Thread.sleep it will be fixed. Other way could be to call the function from the client when the page is loaded, before the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want in the constructor. Your `handleLogin()` method calls `this.getWindow()`, but your the button doesn't have a window until after it (and its parents) have been added to some frame that has been made visible. You have to call `handleLogin()` after the GUI has been fully created and made visible.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new thread that waits and then call the function. I suppose it fails because of the element is not created, meaby with this it is... hope I help.